# SQL How to join 2 tables with or without

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, query-optimization

I have two tables, one with persons and one with contact moments. What I want is to join every person with their maximum contact moment based on the contact date. See the image below.
[image]

I am able to join every person on their maximum contact date where there is a contact moment (so I get the data back for John and Frank in the example above). However I cannot get the persons without a contact moment to show up as well (Bill and Kevin). For that I need help.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
SELECT 
    Person.Id,
    Person.Name,
    Contact.Id
    
FROM
    Person,
    Contact
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT      Contact.PersonId, 
                    MAX(Contact.Date) AS MaxDate
        FROM        Contact
        GROUP BY    Contact.PersonId
    ) GroupedContact ON 
        Contact.PersonId = GroupedContact.PersonId AND 
        Contact.Date = GroupedContact.MaxDate
        
WHERE
    Person.Id = Contact.PersonId
```

I know that the WHERE here causes some of the issue, but if I remove it entirely, my query won't stop running and I get a timeout. Can anyone help me, as I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Precise MySQL version is ... ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the additional unnecessary join to contact:

```
SELECT 
    Person.Id,
    Person.Name,
    GroupedContact.MaxDate as outputCol

FROM
    Person
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT      Contact.PersonId, 
                    MAX(Contact.Date) AS MaxDate
        FROM        Contact
        GROUP BY    Contact.PersonId
    ) GroupedContact ON 
        Person.PersonId = GroupedContact.PersonId
```

A few notes: Never mix implicit and explicit joins. Always use explicit joins. You need here a `LEFT` join which means -> keep all the records from the `LEFT` tables and those that match from the `RIGHT` table.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it gives me the following error:
"The multi-part identifier "Contact.PersonId" could not be bound."

Answer (score 1):

You need LEFT join instead of RIGHT and extra join to contacts is not needed:

```
SELECT 
    Person.Id,
    Person.Name,
    GroupedContact.MaxDate
    
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT      Contact.PersonId, 
                    MAX(Contact.Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM        Contact
    GROUP BY    Contact.PersonId
) GroupedContact 
  ON Person.Id = GroupedContact.PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT person.*,m1.date
FROM contant m1 
LEFT JOIN contant m2
 ON (m1.personID = m2.personID AND m1.id < m2.id)
RIGHT JOIN person ON person.id = m1.personID 
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

[image]